# Displaying search results in a listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm making a biomedical app that serves information and was referred here by. I'm trying to utilize a search function that pulls information from a database (.db file) in the app. The search function appears to be working, but the search leads the user to a blank page. I want the results to be presented in a listview. What do I need to put in my showResults method to create/populate a listview with search data? (I have a layout file (search_results) with a blank listview).

```
    package com.joe.biomarker;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListAdapter;

    public class SearchResultsActivity extends Activity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);

        showResults(query);
    }
}

private void showResults(String query) {
    // Query your data set and show results
    // ...
    Cursor results = mDataTableInstance(query, mColumnsArray);
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getContext(), R.layout.search_results, results, mFromArray, mToArray);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}   

   }
```

Comment: do you want to use a `SearchView` ? if so first use `setOnQueryTextListener (SearchView.OnQueryTextListener listener)` where in listener you can use something like `adapter.getFilter().filter(newText)`

Comment: see the minimalistic approach (~20 lines of real code): https://codeshare.io/aFQT7

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear. If you launch the intent first, you'll have to move the search pull to a background thread. Create an `AsyncTask` for your search function, transfer your adapter as a parameter and override `onPostExecute()` to call `adapter.notifyOnDataSetChanged()` .

Comment: When the user searches for data, a blank screen comes up, and they don't see the search results. I want to make a listview with the search results. How do I put the results of the query into a listview that the user will see?

Comment: First the user searches, then submits? If so, do as I wrote. On the "submit" action - run your `AsyncTask`. Then call `.notifyOnDataSetChanged()` inside `onPoseExecute()`.
Or are you trying to make it like a real-time suggestions?

Comment: Right, the user types something he wants to search into a searchview, then hits enter. The app is supposed to redirect him to another page with a listview containing the search results. Right now the app goes to the second page, but the results are not shown. The second page is just a blank screen.